# SQLite Memory Consumption - Why so high?

Tags: c++, performance, sqlite, memory, memory-leaks

I have a c++ application (Winx64) that I am prototyping and I am noticing that the memory consumption when using SQLite is 6GB in size when the database itself is 200MB on disk.   If I remove all statements which perform database functions, my application never gets above 700MB (which includes the data to be loaded into SQL from internal buffers).

Here is what I am doing:

- Create the database
- Create 10 tables
- Load tables with 1.318 million rows
- Raw data size is 578MB

I have journaling turned off.
Synchronization is turned off.

I am using prepared SQL statements for the inserts.
Batch size for each commit is 1000 records
After each commit, I manually run a PRAGMA shrink_memory and VACUUM

sqlite3_memory_highwater shows only 1.1GB and sqlite3_memory_used shows 700mb.

At the end of the program I run _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); and it shows no memory leaks (other than my class initializer strings).

Why is SQLite using 6GB of RAM (according to the performance monitor for both workingset and private bytes)?

I even tried something along these lines just to make sure it wasn't held up in my constructor:

```
int main(void)
{
    dbClass *db = new dbClass("Sample.db");
    DoWork();
    delete db;
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    cin.get();
}
```

And still shows 5GB allocated.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you paste the performance monitor output?

Comment: Ok, Here are the perfmon screenshots.   The first one is without sqlite and the second is with it.

Comment: Rats...hit enter....here are the links.

Without SQLite:  http://imgur.com/kllYAL7
WithSQLite: http://imgur.com/MgIkZyU

Comment: Your picture doesn't make it possible to see how much RAM is consumed. We can see how much virtual memory is consumed, but virtual memory is basically free. Can you show the actual working set size please? You ask, "Why is SQLite using 6GB of RAM (according to the performance monitor for both workingset and private bytes)" but don't show us this.

Comment: While the image has the virtual bytes selected, true, the dark blue line in the image is working set for that process and the light blue line is for the working set private (which is not easily seen because it is under the working set line).   Virtual bytes are the green lines.   

Is this not what you were looking for?   Or, is there some other value you need?

Comment: You can't see the numerical amounts though. You can't see the max, min, or average. Nothing actually shows very large amounts of physical memory being used.

Comment: David.  Perhaps you can't see the physical numbers, but looking at the graph, the Y axis 100 = 1GB.   The dark blue line shows the scale and they are all on the same scale.   So you can interpolate them using the graph.

If you need the exact numbers, I can go re-run the test and find out.  But I can see from the chart, that the working set levels off after SQL lite has loaded the data and it has been unloaded from RAM (in terms of db.Close()) to about 5.7GB.   You can see this where the green arrow shows.   If you still need something more, I can post it.